# GIMP advice on JPG to PDF conversion

Tags: pdf, conversion, gimp, jpeg

When I convert JPG files to PDF using GIMP the result is usually a much bigger file.

The first step upon importing is the dialog for a conversion that is titled "convert to RGB working space". I just use the defaults settings because I'm unfamiliar with the effects of the possibilities.

Upon exporting to PDF, there is a dialog in which I just use the default settings because I'm unfamiliar with the effects of the possibilities.

The original JPG was 1.1 MB and the PDF is 3.6 MBytes.

I'd like some advice, please, on how to do the conversion without creating a much larger PDF file. In the past, I used a free online PDF compression service but since I need to use GIMP to crop photos, I might as well try to get a smaller file from GIMP and eliminate the use of an online PDF compression service.

Obviously the preference is to avoid a noticeable degradation in visual quality to the eyes of casual users. Since compressed PDFs seem to look good, it would seem that smaller files without a noticeable loss in quality is a reasonable thing to hope for.  I will not need to convert back (from PDF to JPG) if that helps me meet my goals.

Here are the 2 dialogs:

[image: Import dialog]

[image: Export dialog]

Comment: My guess is that Gimp is decompressing the JPEG into its raw samples (the 'first step suggest something like this), then piping that image data to a PDF production module, which uses a lossless compression mode such as Flate, or something similar. You need a tool which will take the JPEG and turn it into a PDF file without processing the DCT encoded samples because doing so will either produce a larger file or hurt quality. I suspect MuPDF's mutool can do this but I am not certain, I would think there would be many tools available, it's a very simple use of PDF.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/myollie/img2pdf which specialises in creating PDFs from JPEG and other images with minimal or no re-processing.

Comment: A JPEG can be embedded into a PDF as is. So the resulting PDF file should only be a few 100 bytes larger than the JPEG file.